# Laravel Spark Sessions

Tags: laravel, session, nginx, laravel-5, laravel-spark

I have a problem with Laravel spark... I've develop an application and after release at server I have problem with sessions.

Sessions are going expired randomly... Once over 6 hours and once over 2-3minutes... It is very weird...

I am using:

- Ubuntu 16.04 at DigitalOcean
- Nginx
- SSL
- Laravel 5.4
- Laravel Spark 4.0 with Braintree

My driver settings (from .env) are

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_DRIVER=database

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Session configs:

```
'lifetime' => 36500
'expire_on_close' => false
'encrypt' => false
'lottery' => [2, 10000]
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: You need to include code where you handle session saves in the database

Comment: Could you please explain it a little bit more? Because I am using session driver REDIS, not database and my auth is normal auth from Laravel Spark

Comment: Have you figured out what went wrong? The same thing is happening to me: sessions expire in seconds or a few minutes

Comment: Sorry for late response but nope... I don't have a solution right now... Still not working.